# Activerecord check if value is not true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to correctly check value in db:
in table i have field `add_after_sign_in` which is boolean, by default it is false... but how to check if it is not empty and not true, then select such rows:
i try:

```
litem = LineItem.find(:all, :conditions => {:cart_id => cart_id && !:add_after_sign_in })
```

but in litem there are no such records... why?
Simple how to check table row value on non-true?

Comment: rails version?? so `only when add_after_sign_in = false`?

Comment: @tokland yes, only if false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conditions` is a Hash. You are only messing up with the syntax. Try this one:

```
litem = LineItem.find(:all, 
  :conditions => {:cart_id => cart_id, :add_after_sign_in => [nil, false]})
```

Comment: This method is deprecated in newer versions of Rails. `where` is the appropriate scoping method going forward.

Comment: OP, you say you didn't want NULL values, did you?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use symbols like this (but note that you can do similar things with [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) and Rails 3).

I'd write (note that it's `line_items`, it's a collection):

```
line_items = LineItem.where(:cart_id => cart_id, :add_after_sign_in => false)
```

However, with a sound model structure and named scopes you should be able to write more declarative code:

```
line_items = Cart.find(cart_id).line_items.without_add_after_sign_in
```

Comment: Always be careful to handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exceptions when using `find`.

Comment: @Valdis: You can decide to a) return an empty array, or b) raise an exception. Personally I'd prefer the method to blow up right away if non-existing IDs are being passed.

Comment: @tadman such code: litem = LineItem.find(:all, 
  :conditions => {:cart_id => cart_id, :add_after_sign_in => [nil, false]})  didn't thrrow exception for me, or what>

Comment: `find(:all)` won't throw exceptions, but `find(1)` will.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `where` for a more readable syntax:

```
litem = LineItem.where(cart_id: cart_id, add_after_sign_in: [nil, false])
```

or, with scopes:

```
class LineItem
  scope :not_added_after_sign_in, where(add_after_sign_in: [nil, false])
  #...
end

litem = LineItem.where(cart_id: cart_id).not_added_after_sign_in
```

**Edit:** tweaked after [tokland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188031/tokland)'s answer.